# Python: Lucky sevens game (Average number of dice rolls)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a count function, to calculate the number of rolls it takes to hit 0. And it is returning me the random integer of the diceroll + 1, how do I get it to count the number of times the myroll variable occurs.

```
import random


def luckysevens():
    mypot = int(input("Please enter the amount of money you want to in the pot: "))

    while mypot > 0:
        diceroll = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(diceroll)
        myroll = (diceroll + diceroll)
        if myroll == 7:
            mypot = mypot + 4
            print("Your roll was a 7 you earned 4$", mypot)
        else:
            mypot = mypot - 1
            print("Your roll was", myroll, "you lost 1$", mypot)
    if mypot == 0:
        print("Your out of money!")
    sum = 0
    for count in range(myroll + 1):
        sum = sum + count
    print(count)


luckysevens()
```

Comment: what does mypot start off as ?

Comment: what's the need for myroll = (diceroll + diceroll)? myroll will never hit 7 if this is the case ...

Comment: Do you want to count how many times die are rolled?

Comment: mypot is an input, and im trying to count the number of times the die is rolled. Two dice are being rolled in this program, that is the reason for my roll. There was originally 2 different dice variables, but I cut it down to 1.

Comment: You need two different dice variables, since the random function needs to be re-calculated :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count how many rolls before the loop exits, simply add another counter variable. I also am assuming you're rolling a couple dice, so added different random calls for each one.

```
import random

mypot = int(input("Please enter the amount of money you want to in the pot: "))

num_rolls = 0
while mypot > 0:
    die_1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die_2 = random.randint(1,6)

    myroll = die_1 + die_2

    num_rolls += 1 # count rolls

    if myroll == 7:
        mypot = mypot + 4
        print("Your roll was a 7 you earned 4$",mypot)
    else:
        mypot = mypot - 1
        print("Your roll was",myroll,"you lost 1$",mypot)

if mypot == 0:
    print("Your out of money!")

print 'Num rolls: {}'.format(num_rolls) # print rolls
```